# Gradle sync failed- Android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I installed Android studio 3.0.1 on macbook pro, but when I opened a new project file it can't be build and says like Gradle sync failed. Is there any solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you click the "Install Build Tools 26.0.2 and sync project" link? Usually that's all it takes.